# Information about how many files to compile before build in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005

How can I figure out, how many files needs to be recompiled *before* I start the build process.

Sometimes I don't remember how many basic header files I changed so a Rebuild All would be better than a simple build. There seams to be no option for this, but IMHO it must be possible (f.e. XCode give me this information).

**Update:**

My problem is not, that Visual Studio doesn't know what to compile. I need to know how much it *will* compile so that I can decide if I can make a quick test with my new code or if I should write more code till I start the "expensive" build process. Or if my boss ask "When can I have the new build?" the best answer is not "It is done when it is done!".

It's really helpful when the IDE can say *"compile 200 of 589 files"* instead of *"compile x,y, ..."*

Comment: Does this need to be within Visual Studio? You could write a quick app or script that loops over all the source and object files and compares their modified dates to decide how many would need to be rebuilt if not.

Comment: It's not that easy. If I will change an important header file (which is included in a lot of other cpp files) basically the whole projects needs to be rebuild. Only the linker can know how much files are really needed to be recompiled.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's true. I suppose you could attempt to parse that but it'd be a pain handling #ifdefs around #includes and #includes on #defines.

Answer (score 1):

Could your version control tell you this? For example in Subversion "Check for modifications" will list everything changed since your last checkin (although not since your last build)

Mind you, doesn't "build" automatically do exactly that? (build only what's changed)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually Visual Studio is good at knowing what needs to be compiled for you.

If you have multiple projects in a solution then just make sure your solution dependencies are set up correctly and it should just work when you hit Build.